# How do I use Ant to build multiple Android APKs with the same code base, but with different resource files?

Tags: android, ant, build

I am trying to build a branded Android app, that will have different resource files (mainly drawables) for different customers. The Java code in the apps will be the same, but the different apps will have a different look--meaning different color schemes and different logos etc. I have been told, and my research suggests that Ant is the best way to achieve this.

Where should I change the Android 'build.xml' file? What sort of Ant task should I use to achieve this?

For debugging, I would like to just use Eclipse and build with the default resources. But for production releases, I would like to run Ant on build.xml to produce multiple APKs from different /res folders. I do not even need any code snippets (although that would be nice), just even some tips from people that have done this before or something similar.

Comment: I ended up writing a Python script to reorganize the Android project before each build.  I recommend avoiding the use of Ant for stuff like this.  My 100-200 lines of Python achieved the equivalent of about 1000+ extra lines of Ant that was required in addition to the default Android build.xml Ant script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a Python script to reorganize the Android project before each build. I recommend avoiding the use of Ant for stuff like this. My 100-200 lines of Python achieved the equivalent of about 1000+ extra lines of Ant that was required in addition to the default Android build.xml Ant script.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue where I want to compile the same code base with some changes as well as changes in the resource files. The solution I am pursuing at the moment is creating a library with the shared code/resources and separate "regular" projects for each of the different APK releases. Unfortunately, I don't have a functional final solution to the problem yet, so all I can give is these vague hints.

Comment: This may be the solution I use.  I am now looking over ant to see if I can write an automated build process that can switch library references on the fly.  I will let you know if this works for me. Thanks.

Comment: I have used the `android update-project` command to configure the Ant script to use a single library. If you can explain what you are trying to solve by "switching library references on the fly", perhaps I can give some suggestions for alternative solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Requirement Setup

**1.** Go to the URL :

http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi

and download the apache ant and extract it in to the any folder like d:/ant .

**2.** I think you already having the Android SDK path is like(D:/Android SDK/)

Now go to the Enviroment variables and check whether path variable is there is there add these in path otherwise create a new varible with name path and put it there in vaue

**D:/ant/bin;D:/Android SDK/tools**

done

Go to command prompt and navigate it to the root directory of your project and run the command

```
android update project -p /
```

*Note: / if you are in the root directory of project else you need to give the path of root directory like d:/myworkspace/mysampleproject*

this will generate and build.xml file in your project.

now run the command for this it is necessary to be in root directory of your project

```
ant debug
```

this will generate an apk file in bin folder signed with default debug key.

Comment: This was not what I asked.  Installing and running Ant is quite trivial and is not what I need help with.